# How to fix "Uncaught ReferenceError" in a for..in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, referenceerror

When I'm using a for..of loop, the iterator value throws a "ReferenceError" when I try to run it.

I've tried changing the for...of loop into a for...in loop, but to no avail. I suspect that it has something to do with the script tagged as a module, or it might be my `utils.js` file, but I removed them and I still get the same server. I'm getting this error on Chrome 76 on Windows 10.

Here's the code:

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
        Bruh. are you using IE?!
    </canvas>
    <script type="module">
        import { Mouse, Screen } from "./utils.js"

        let attractionForce = 1;
        let friction = 0.99;

        let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        //let mouse = new Mouse(canvas);
        const PI_2 = Math.PI * 2;

        var points = Array.from({ length: 1000 }, () => ({
            x: Math.random() * 800,
            y: Math.random() * 600,
            dx: (Math.random() - 0.5),
            dy: (Math.random() - 0.5),
        }));

        for (pti of points) console.log(pti); << Uncaught ReferenceError: pti is not defined
    </script>
</body>
```

Normally, it would just iterate over the loop, but now it's throwing an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [your code works fine](https://jsbin.com/govidoveha/edit?js,console).

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. [The entire contents of JavaScript modules are automatically in strict mode, with no statement needed to initiate it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Strict_mode_for_modules) There, it does indeed throw a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte - good catch. should have made it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts of `type="module"` [use strict mode automatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#Other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts). Hence,  because `pti` is not defined before use, you get the reference error.

Obviously the cure is to make sure `pti` is defined. You can declare it as a variable in a `for.. in` loop, but you have to declare it before starting a `for...of` loop because the syntax of the latter does not support variable definitions in the control structure.

Code evaluation outside a module type script element won't reproduce the error without invoking strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe missing declaration of pti

Try to change `for (pti of points) console.log(pti);` to `for (let pti of points) console.log(pti);`

Comment: omitting `let` creates a global variable. it's not ideal, but it isn't breaking anything either.

Comment: i was wrong. this answer contains the solution, the other answer contains the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code in chrome develop tools

```
 var points = Array.from({ length: 1 }, () => ({
     x: Math.random() * 800,
     y: Math.random() * 600,
     dx: (Math.random() - 0.5),
     dy: (Math.random() - 0.5),
 }));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlSXY.png)

no key `pti`